# Fix Indicator width in TabRow - Jetpack Compose Material design

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

TabRow has default indicator that spans the entire width of the selected Tab. Is it possible to set the width of this indicator, I was trying to make it so that it takes the length of the text but that is proving even more tricky (was able to achieve this using Scrollable Tab Row) but not working for TabRow.

```
Column {
val tabs = listOf("Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3")
TabRow(selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
    divider = { CustomDivider() },
    contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    indicator = { tabPositions ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[pagerState.currentPage])
                .height(2.dp)
                .width(2.dp) // Set the fixed width for the indicator
                .background(selectedTabIndicatorColor)
        )
    }
) {
    tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides CustomRippleTheme) {
            Tab(text = {
                Text(
                    title,
                    color = if (pagerState.currentPage == index) selectedTabTextColor else unselectedTabTextColor,
                    fontWeight = if (pagerState.currentPage == index) FontWeight.Bold else FontWeight.Normal
                )
            },
                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                selectedContentColor = Color.Gray,
                onClick = { scope.launch { pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index) } })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The composable passed as the `indicator` will be forced to take the entire tab width by applying `tabIndicatorOffset` modificator. One way around this is to wrap the actual indicator in another composable.

```
indicator = { tabPositions ->
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[currentPage]),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(5.dp)
                .width(10.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        )
    }
}
```

Or you could add horizontal `padding`.

```
indicator = { tabPositions ->
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[currentPage])
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
            .height(2.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Red)
        )
}
```